# Из-за чего происходит такая ошибка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.tech {
  background-image: url(second__bg.jpg);
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tech__item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 140px;

}

.tech__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 308px; 
}

.number {
  font-size: 72px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #111;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.mg {
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #18a3dd;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.per {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #6b696e;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="tech">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tech__item">
      <h1 class="number">100</h1>
      <div class="mg">MG</div>
      <div class="perper">Per Capsule</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="tech__item">
      <h1 class="number">60</h1>
      <div class="mg">Capsules</div>
      <div class="perper">Per Bottle</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="tech__item">
      <h1 class="number">900</h1>
      <div class="mg">PLUS</div>
      <div class="per">Satisfied Customers</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Какая ошибка? Можете подробнее описать проблему.